# JPG decompressed and compressed again, will it affect colors and color space?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image, transforms, compression

I found easy to add a black frames to my photos with Blender. I just add some scaling and offset in VSE and render one image. I am wondering is that process affects colors or color space of my photo? Is my JPG decompressed and compressed again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color space is the same: sRGB, so expect no transformation there, but know that Jpeg is a compressed format, a lossy compression format designed to make file sizes small at the expense of quality. A terrible format if you are applying transformations.

Every time you decompress an image, change the geometry or color, and re-compress the image again you will get new compression artifacts. Do an image search for "macroblocking" and "compression artifacts" to understand the horrors of the JPEG format.

Comment: In fact I observed the quality loss. Wandered if this is more caused by the JPG format or scaling resolution, cause a new pixels must be somehow recalculated.